# Docker Desktop for Windows container is not starting with -m 4g but works fine with -m 3g

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I have a clean install of **Docker Desktop for windows** in Windows containers mode.
OS is Windows 10 Pro, machine has 32 Gb RAM, OS is running on physical machine, not a VM.

Command

```
docker run -ti -m 3g microsoft/nanoserver cmd
```

Works fine, but

```
docker run -ti -m 4g microsoft/nanoserver cmd
```

Cannot start and basically says "connection could not be established with the Virtual Machine hosting the Container".

Can anyone confirm or deny that the 2nd command is failing to work?

Comment: Maybe some docker configuration? I don't know for Windows, but for Mac there is a memory limit pre-assigned

Comment: I was thinking kind of the same, but where is that memory limit set on Mac?

Comment: When you click the whale icon. Do you have one?

Comment: Have you find a solution?

Comment: No I didn't, I created an isuue on Github, here is the link if you want to follow it. https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/767

Comment: Thank you and good luck with it.

Comment: So can anyone on Windows 10 confirm this problem?

Comment: Yes, I am having the problem too.  I just can't find a way to run my Ubuntu container on Docker for Windows with more than 3 GB total.  Also - hyper-v needs to be on to run Docker for Windows (which makes sense) but this prevents VMWare Workstation from running VM's, and especially on development machines the VM approach is less 'heavy' and I'd like to be able to do that too.  Aah, well, looks like Docker for Windows isn't really ready for prime time.